# PHP grouping based on a value

Tags: php

I'm asking in arbitrary sense to avoid going into any unwanted specifics.

Suppose we're to put balls in baskets.
If the there are <6 balls, they don't get to go in any basket.
If there are between 6-12 balls they take up 1 basket.
But if the balls are >12, they take up 2 baskets.

Following is WORKING FINE:

```
if (count($balls)<=5) {
    $baskets = 0;
} else if (count($balls) > 5 && count($balls) <12) {
    $baskets = 1;
} else {
    $answer = ceil(count($balls)/12);
}
```

Question: Is there a better, smarter, and/or quicker way to approach the problem, may be through loops or something?

Comment: The only special case here seems to be `<= 5`, everything above 5 is always `ceil(count($balls) / 12)`, no?

Comment: The test `count($balls) > 5` is redundant. The code takes the `else` branch when the condition `count($balls)<=5` is `FALSE` and this means `count($balls) > 5`.

Comment: `ceil(count($balls)/12)`  this will not evaluate to 2 when count is 12.

Comment: "6-12 balls they take up 1 basket. But if the balls are 12" do you mean "But if the balls are greater than 12"

Comment: Sorry about the confusion I meant '>12'. You're right, my if-else is redundant

Comment: Would 25 balls take up 2 baskets or 3 baskets?

Comment: 25 balls would take up 3 baskets

Comment: Why are you sometimes declaring `$baskets` and sometimes declaring `$answer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The middle else if statement is redundent and can be removed. The reason that is redundent is that the only two cases are either equal or less than 5 balls gives 0 baskets and for everything else the number of baskets can be evaluated to be ceil(count($balls)/12).

Also using short hand will make it more readable I find.

```
$baskets = count($balls) <=5 ? 0 : ceil(count($balls)/12);
```

Answer (score 2):

A common style in programming is to save values you use repeatedly, also if you checked that `count <= 5`, and it failed, then you know `count > 5`, so you don't need to verify that, finally it's good style to use the same kind of comparisons when you can e.g. `<=` or `<` to reduce mental workload. Taking all this into consideration, here's a revision:

```
$cnt = count($balls);

if ($cnt < 6)
    $baskets = 0;
else if ($cnt < 12)
    $baskets = 1;
else
    $answer = ceil($cnt / 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this one.

```
function baskets($count_of_balls){
  return $count_of_balls < 12 ? ($count_of_balls > 5 ? 1 : 0) : 2;
}
```

I don't know the other conditions, and have already stated in comments that,

```
ceil($count_of_balls/12)
```

will never evaluate to 2 when count is 12.

As @Barmar [commmented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192840/php-grouping-based-on-a-value/192843#comment370543_192843)

```
    function baskets($count_of_balls){
      return $count_of_balls <= 5 ? 0 : ($balls < 12 ? 1 : 2))
    }
```

is better option.

Comment: It need not be. evaluate to 2 when count is >12. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would need to double-check the parameter name...

Comment: IMHO nested ternaries are usually a bad idea, although this one happens to be simple enough that it's still understandable.

Comment: But I'd probably reorder it to `$balls <= 5 ? 0 : ($balls < 12 ? 1 : 2))` so the order matches the description, and the comparisons are in consistent directions.